# glut and nvidia-cg dependency problem when Installing rviz on mac osx

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install rviz on mac osx 10.6 and get the following messages

Failed to find rosdep glut for package rviz on OS:macports version:macports
Failed to find rosdep nvidia-cg for package rviz on OS:macports version:macports
ERROR: ABORTING: Rosdeps [u'glut', u'nvidia-cg'] could not be resolved

Any ideas on what to do next?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10627/glut-and-nvidia-cg-dependency-problem-when-installing-rviz-on-mac-osx/) by [1el](https://answers.ros.org/users/851/1el/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-07-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-18**:
Please try and make sure your headlines are descriptive. (I fixed this one for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been a great problem. However, there is a successful workaround that is very well documented in this wiki https://github.com/wjwwood/ros-osx/wiki including some troubleshooting tips.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2